# The story of Satya Bama and Narakasura

Tags: krishna, satyabhama

Satya Bama another incarnation of Lakshmi killed Narakasura who had a boon that only his mother could kill him, Being the son of Krishna and Satya Bama How can he be an asura? Is this story mentioned in other Puranas like the Devi Bhagavatha Purana? Does the Devi Bhagavatha Purana mention Goddess Lakshmi's incarnations?

Answer (score 1):

Narakasura was killed by Lord Krishna himself, not Satyabhama.

*Fighting with Naraka for a moment the dreadful Janardana cut him into two pieces with his effulgent discus. His body, sundered into twain with the discus, fell on earth like a mountain summit clapped by a thunder-bolt. It appeared that the sun was enshrouded by Krishna-like black clouds.*

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/harivamsha-purana-dutt/d/doc485605.html

*Having slain Mum, Hayagriva, and Pañcajana, the wise Hari rapidly reached the city of Prāgjyotiṣa: there a fierce conflict took place with the troops of Naraka, in which Govinda destroyed thousands of demons; and when Naraka came into the field, showering upon the deity all sorts of weapons, the wielder of the discus, and annihilator of the demon tribe, cut him in two with his celestial missile.*

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc116051.html

*His attempt having been thus frustrated, Naraka, the son of the Earth goddess, took up his spear to strike at Kṛṣṇa, but before he could hurl it, Hari, with his discus (Sudarśana) of razor-like sharp edge, severed the head of Naraka who was riding on elephant.*

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-bhagavata-purana/d/doc1128933.html